# Mageplaza Magento 2 Products Slider Category ID not working?

Tags: magento2, category, products, cms, slider

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-product-slider

When using the CMS shortcode for selecting a category:

```
{{block class="Mageplaza\Productslider\Block\CategoryId" template="Mageplaza_Productslider::productslider.phtml" products_count="8" heading="test heading" category_id="5" description="test"}}
```

the `category_id` field apparently is wrong/incorrect? My **category 5** is a `child category` of the **Default Category in Magento 2.2.7**

I get the following error:

> Error filtering template: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MYFOLDER/vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-product-slider/Block/CategoryId.php
>   on line 96

Can anyone help ASAP?

I have products within this category so it should be fine?

Comment: Put screenshot of your categories with selection of category which have id 5.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the Magento version some of version its working fine and for some of version its not working.

To solve the problem, you should add the following code in 2 files:

- app/code/Mageplaza/Productslider/Block/CategoryId.php
- app/code/Mageplaza/Productslider/Block/AbstractSlider.php

-At Category.php file, change

```
foreach ($catIds as $catId) {
            $category   = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($catId);
```

in line 96 & 97 into

```
if ($this->getSlider()) {
            foreach ($catIds as $catId) {
                $category   = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($catId);
                $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addCategoryFilter($category);

                foreach ($collection as $item) {
                    $productIds[] = $item->getData('entity_id');
                }
            }
        }
        if ($this->getData('category_id')) {
            $category   = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($catIds);
```

At AbstractSlider.php, change code in function getDisplayAdditional() into

```
public function getDisplayAdditional()
    {
        if($this->getSlider()) {
            $display = $this->getSlider()->getDisplayAdditional();
            if (!is_array($display)) {
                $display = explode(',', $display);
            }
        }
        else{
            $display = $this->_helperData->getModuleConfig('general/display_information');
            if (!is_array($display)) {
                $display = explode(',', $display);
            }
        }
        return $display;
    }
```

Reference :You can check the below Git URL they have given some solution :

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-product-slider/issues/31

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-product-slider/issues/49